# How do I save multiple specific child elements from a Linq query?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

The XML file looks like this

```
<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.0.2">
  <bounds minlat="54.0889580" minlon="12.2487570" maxlat="54.0913900" maxlon="12.2524800"/>
  <node id="298884269" lat="54.0901746" lon="12.2482632" user="SvenHRO" uid="46882" visible="true" version="1" changeset="676636" timestamp="2008-09-21T21:37:45Z"/>
  <node id="261728686" lat="54.0906309" lon="12.2441924" user="PikoWinter" uid="36744" visible="true" version="1" changeset="323878" timestamp="2008-05-03T13:39:23Z"/>
  <way id="11103644" visible="true" version="22" changeset="57021161" timestamp="2018-03-09T06:06:21Z" user="thetornado76" uid="1624486">
   <nd ref="5058358201"/>
   <nd ref="5058358200"/>
   <nd ref="459672758"/>
   <nd ref="459672757"/>
   <nd ref="459672756"/>
   <tag k="bicycle" v="no"/>
   <tag k="destination" v="Airport"/>
 </way>
 <way id="11103973" visible="true" version="1" changeset="410956" timestamp="2007-11-05T15:10:28Z" user="DaveHansenTiger" uid="7168">
   <nd ref="98983980"/>
   <nd ref="98983981"/>
   <tag k="tiger:source" v="tiger_import_dch_v0.6_20070809"/>
   <tag k="tiger:tlid" v="116306702"/>
   <tag k="tiger:upload_uuid" v="bulk_upload.pl-bcfe2a6c-15d8-4c58-8cb2-f0d6e1120159"/>
 </way>
</osm>
```

This is what I have so far

```
//Removes the "tag" element from xml
osmFile.Root.Elements().Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "tag").Remove();

//Each iteration of query has the an entire <way> elements and all its children
var query = from c in osmFile.Root.Elements("way")
            select c;
```

My question is, how do I make it so that each iteration of going over query has only the all the attribute values of the nd elements for a particular way?

For example, if I do

```
foreach (var x in query)
    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
```

The first iteration would show

```
5058358201
5058358200
459672758
459672757
459672756
```

And the second would show

```
98983980
98983981
```

Also, is there a way of achieving this without removing all the tag elements first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select anything from the xml without modifying it:

```
var items = osmFile.Root
    .Elements("way")
    .Select(x => x.Elements("nd")
                    .Select(z => z.Attribute("ref").Value));

foreach (var item in items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, item));
}
```

you will need to add `using System.Linq;` if you do not have it alrady.

Answer (score 0):

Im not used to work in the query linq form. With lambda expression it should be:

```
osmFile.Root.Elements("way").forEach(wayElement => 
{
var ndElements = wayElement.Where(wayChildElement => wayChildElement.name == "nd");
ndElements.forEach(ndElement => Console.WritteLine(ndElement ););
});
```

I could not try this code but it should work. You can not achieve all the functionality with linq because linq is for data query, not iteration data. The provided solution is a one line solution but feel free to implement a different way.